# Passing parameters in HIVE query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to pass a parameter into an HQL at execution time. For this we have updated the .param file with the required value. Now I am facing issue in using it.

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table A 
WHERE PRODT_CTGRY_CD = 'CAR' AND
(
    (DATE(A.CUST_BRTH_DT) BETWEEN concat(${hiveconf:PRODYEAR} - 13 ,"-02","-28") and  concat(${hiveconf:PRODYEAR} - 7 ,"-03","-01")
 AND DATE(A.TERM_DT) >= concat(${hiveconf:PRODYEAR} - 1 ,"-03","-31")
)
```

In the above query if I don't include the condition of term_dt the query is running fine. However when I include that I am getting an error as below:

```
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableIntObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Can someone let me know what needs to be done here?

Comment: I just figured that the return types being compared are not same so I was getting the error. So I have used to_date before each of the concat statements and I was able to get rid of the error.

Comment: (
TO_DATE(A.CUST_BRTH_DT) BETWEEN TO_DATE(concat(${hiveconf:PRODYEAR} - 13 ,"-02","-28")) and TO_DATE(concat(${hiveconf:PRODYEAR} - 7 ,"-03","-01"))

AND

TO_DATE(A.TERM_DT) >= TO_DATE(concat(${hiveconf:PRODYEAR} - 1 ,"-03","-31"))

)

Comment: Hi @kiran kvs, you can add that as an answer below so that it is easier to find for anyone who is looking for it.